# calling a function using its name as a string when using webpack

Tags: javascript, namespaces, webpack

For an app not running through webpack you can call a function from a string value of its name

```
var fnstr= 'Cat'
var fn = window[fnstr]
if (typeof fn === "function") fn();
```

but functions in webpack are not in the `window` namespace. How can I call a function using its name as a string  when using webpack?

Comment: Are you referring to functions within files that are loaded into webpack? Are you building using NodeJS modules or similar?

Comment: You don't. You either use `eval`, or you put exactly those functions that you want to be callable in an object.

Comment: @Pineda I am working in the frontend. `Cat` is one of the functions I've written in the app. @Bergi your second suggestion works, essentially creating a namespace for it. Funny though `const ca = eval('Cat') comes back as `uncaught reference error`